Calculating charge transfer length in TDDFT calculation - Checking for charge transfer states
I am calculating conjugated organic systems using vertical excitation TD-DFT in Gaussian 16.
My specific command is
CAM-B3LYP/6-311+G(d,p) scrf=(cpcm,solvent=water) guess=check geom=check TD=(Nstates=7,singlets)
which takes the optimized geometry (from the same level of theory) and calculates low-lying singlet states (no TDA approximation).
These systems may be charge-transfer type excitations so I am trying use the Δr metric (as proposed in https://doi.org/10.1021/ct400337e in equation 10) to test if my excited states are trustworthy at my level of theory.
To calculate this value, I will need the excitation and de-excitation values and the orbital centroids, both of which I am struggling to locate.
Is this a matter of specific IOp values to output this information from Gaussian 16 or is there a better way, such as using Multiwfn on the Gaussian output files?
I would greatly appreciate any help on this matter.
